# Is is possible to define a custom error message for login failure in Salesforce communities

Tags: customer-community, community-builder, login-errors

When a user fails to login due to wrong user id or password in salesforce communities the default error message displayed is "Please check your username and password. If you still can't log in, contact your Salesforce administrator."

Is there a way to customize this error message. Or do we have any other options. Kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will start with - the message you get on the login page is very secured. You should in fact have messages that way which really do not classify if the username or password was incorrect. That in a way ensures that any unauthorized user does not get any specific information around which field actually was incorrect.

As for customization options - you **cannot** if you are just using the out of the box configurations. But you do have an option if you customize the login flow by customizing the login component in combination of login apex controllers for that purpose.

You can find more information on customization options on the help documentation here:

- [Customize Your Community’s Login Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_customize_login_page.htm&type=5)
- [Customize Code for Lightning Components on Login Pages](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_custom_login_self_reg_lightning.htm&type=5)